# Golang testing of functions declared as variable (testify)

Tags: go, testify

I have a problem firing a function declared as variable in golang with testify.

Test and function both declared in same package.

```
var testableFunction = func(abc string) string {...}
```

now i have a different file with unit test calling testableFunction

```
func TestFunction(t *testing.T){
     ...
     res:=testableFunction("abc")
     ...
}
```

Calling TestFunction with `go test` does not fire any exception, but testableFunction is actually never run. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your `testableFunction` variable gets assigned somewhere else in your code.

See this example:

```
var testableFunction = func(s string) string {
    return "re: " + s
}
```

Test code:

```
func TestFunction(t *testing.T) {
    exp := "re: a"
    if got := testableFunction("a"); got != exp {
        t.Errorf("Expected: %q, got: %q", exp, got)
    }
}
```

Running `go test -cover`:

```
PASS
coverage: 100.0% of statements
ok      play    0.002s
```

Obviously if a new function value is assigned to `testableFunction` before the test execution, then the anonymous function used to initialize your variable will not get called by the test.

To demonstrate, change your test function to this:

```
func TestFunction(t *testing.T) {
    testableFunction = func(s string) string { return "re: " + s }

    exp := "re: a"
    if got := testableFunction("a"); got != exp {
        t.Errorf("Expected: %q, got: %q", exp, got)
    }
}
```

Running `go test -cover`:

```
PASS
coverage: 0.0% of statements
ok      play    0.003s
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do u know how to reassign it back to the initial function?

Comment: I think I've found the solution. Simply create a temporary variable to keep the initial function. After the second assignment, then put the initial function back to the variable.